# How to inject value into field in groovy script from java via reflection api?

Tags: java, groovy

Very simple groovy script:

```
@Field
List list

def execute(Object args) {
    return list[0]
}
```

I try to write simple code in java:

```
final GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();
final File file = new File("<path to groovy file>");
GroovyCodeSource groovyCodeSource = new GroovyCodeSource(file);
final Class groovyClass = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyCodeSource);
final List<String> testList = Collections.singletonList("test");
final Binding context = new Binding();
context.setVariable("list", testList );
final Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(groovyClass, context);
final Field list = groovyClass.getField("list");
list.setAccessible(true);
list.set(null, testList );
final Object returnValue = script.invokeMethod("execute", null);
```

But in field groovyClass.getField("list"); I get exception NoSuchFieldException
Could you please help me? Why is it happened?

Comment: First idea: Javadoc for ```Class::getField()``` says: "Returns a Field object that reflects the specified *public* member field of the class or interface represented by this Class object." – What is the default visibility for a field in Groovy?

Comment: Second idea: what will be the output from ```groovyClass.getFields()```?

Comment: Third idea: What about using ```Class::getDeclaredField()```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what was written in the original code, I assume that the default visibility of a field in Groovy is `private`; otherwise the call to `list.setAccessible(true)` would be redundant, if not obsolete.

But the Javadoc for [`Class::getField(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String)) says "Returns a Field object that reflects the specified *public* member field of the class or interface represented by this Class object."

From that I would guess that changing the code like below should do the job:

```
…
final Script script = InvokerHelper.createScript(groovyClass, context);
final Field list = groovyClass.getDeclaredField("list");
list.setAccessible(true);
…
```

See the [respective Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)).